# Python-Docx: Identify an italicized paragraph

Tags: python, python-docx

Now, the following code is supposed to look through a word file, check whether the first character is a pipeline character, then save the index number of the paragraph to slide_list for each appearance of the pipeline character. It's meant to add pipeline characters in italic to their own list. (using the latest python-docx v0.8.11)

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document(r'C:\example.docx')

slide_list = []
italicized_list = []
slide_char = '|'

for i, paragraph in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):
    #Avoids IndexError from blank paragraphs
    if not paragraph.text:
        continue

    #Looks for slide_char in paragraph, saves position of paragraph to slide_list
    if paragraph.text[0] == slide_char:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            for char in run.text[:50]:
                #Checks whether char is italicized and skips if so
                if char == slide_char and not run.italic:
                    slide_list.append(i)
                elif char == slide_char:
                    italicized_list.append(i)
```

Looks good, right? Unfortunately, this doesn't work reliably. For one, it fails to identify a pipeline character as italicized when the entire paragraph is italicized. For another, in some files, randomly, it fails to identify even italicized runs.

I'll attach [test file 1](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AmInvV-Q30YlgdI1VCbYk6hdEK8f9A?e=hKX7Fz) where the first paragraph fails to be recognized as italicized by the code, and [test file 2](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AmInvV-Q30YlgdE8Ia08C6K5ExaLxA?e=vyET1X) where the code somehow fails to recognize any italicized pipeline characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is that you're looking for *effective* font (character-formatting) and `run.italic` only gives you *explicit* (directly applied) font.

Here's a little discussion to help you understand better what is happening. The short version is that character formatting is determined by a *style hierarchy*, similar conceptually to how Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) work in HTML. You can find more on this topic by searching `python-docx effective font` and `python-docx style hierarchy`.

If you look at the XML for the first paragraph in `test_file_.docx`:

```
  <w:body>
    <w:p w14:paraId="12B2FDB3" w14:textId="685EC091" w:rsidR="00F54C1D" w:rsidRPr="008E07F1" w:rsidRDefault="00F54C1D" w:rsidP="00491AE4">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:after="0"/>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="SchwacheHervorhebung"/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r w:rsidRPr="008E07F1">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="SchwacheHervorhebung"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>|</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR="00A20FF1" w:rsidRPr="008E07F1">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="SchwacheHervorhebung"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> Titelblatt</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

you can see that the runs are all assigned the character style `"SchwacheHervohebung"` ("weak highlighting"). I expect that if you check that style you'll find it to be the source of the italic character formatting.

The second document is generally the same, except that it occasionally has explicit italic formatting applied to some runs and some paragraphs:

```
    <w:p w14:paraId="3855D66E" w14:textId="7473C028" w:rsidR="006F7489" w:rsidRDefault="001D1280" w:rsidP="006F7489">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="SchwacheHervorhebung"/>
          <w:i w:val="0"/>
          <w:iCs w:val="0"/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="SchwacheHervorhebung"/>
          <w:iCs w:val="0"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">| | </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR="00F93AA1">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="SchwacheHervorhebung"/>
          <w:i w:val="0"/>
          <w:iCs w:val="0"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Frühsozialismus</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

The italic formatting applied at `w:p/w:pPr/w:rPr/w:i` is *default paragraph formatting* and will apply to runs in the paragraph that do not explicitly contradict it. Here since it is `<w:i w:val="0"/>` (`0` being equivalent to "false"), it "turns off" the italic formatting effected by the style for any runs in that paragraph that are silent on italics. In this case, both runs *also* set italic off and so it is their setting which is effective (even though it is the same as the nearest ancestor setting).

Comment: Great feedback! Seems as though I've encountered a bug in Word in tandem with this.
Somehow, Word is unable to revert any style within the document to "Normal"; every run in the document has the 'Subtle Emphasis' style applied, even when the "Normal" style button is pressed. Bizarre.

Comment: There are both _paragraph_ styles and _character_ styles. A paragraph style may have a character style linked to it, but the styles in your document that are applied to runs (`<w:rStyle>` elements) are character styles. Changing a paragraph style may not remove directly applied character styles like you have here. Also, there is some way to remove all applied styles from text, or used to be at least. I vaguely remember it being highlight-and-press-Ctrl-Space back in the day. Anyway, might be something worth searching up to see if that will help in this case.