# Why does Python not correctly identify the italic font in docx files?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I use Python to detect all Italic Fonts from a docx file. The problem: is doesn't find all the Italic Fonts, just some of them. For example in bebe.docx I have the next 4 lines, all have Italic Font. Times new Roman (13).

```
Bebe.

Bebe este acasa maine.

- Bebe.

- The Little Mermaid sighed and looked sadly at her fish tail.
```

This is the simple Python code to check:

```
from docx import Document

for para in Document('bebe.docx').paragraphs:

    for run in para.runs:

        print(f"Text: {run.text}, Bold: {run.bold}, Italic: {run.italic}")
```

None of them can be identified with Italic, although in the .docx they are with italic font. However, the Bold font is recognized very well. Look here what Python finds:

```
Text: Bebe, Bold: None, Italic: None
Text: ., Bold: None, Italic: None
Text: Bebe, Bold: True, Italic: None
Text:  este acasa maine., Bold: None, Italic: None
Text: - Bebe, Bold: None, Italic: None
Text: ., Bold: None, Italic: None
Text: - The Little Mermaid sighed and looked sadly at her fish tail., Bold: None, Italic: None
```

**Some people seem to get the code working, it detects italic. Why doesn't it detect for me?**

Comment: Super. Then an even better question. Why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: Try `run.font.italic`, or perhaps `run.style.font.italic`.  I believe that `run.italic` is only testing whether this particular run of text had explicitly been formatted as italic, rather than inheriting a document-wide style.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995161/python-docx-identify-an-italicized-paragraph) for a more in-depth answer on detecting character formatting. tl;dr is that Word, like HTML/CSS has a _style hierarchy_ and the visible character formatting is computed from that hierarchy. So words that appear in italic do not always have `Run.italic` always directly applied.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was with Styles.

In order for Python to correctly see Bold, Italic, Underline fonts, I must first create a new style. First I must "Clear Formatting" -> "Create a style" -> "Save style"

**After change style, you can test your file with this Python code:**

```
from docx import Document
import re

def get_text_style(run):
    """Returns the text style of the given run.

    Args:
        run: A docx.run.Run object.

    Returns:
        A string containing the text style of the run.
    """
    bold = "True" if run.bold else "False"
    italic = "True" if run.italic else "False"

    return f"Bold: {bold}, Italic: {italic}"

def split_into_sentences(text):
    return re.split(r'(?<=[.!?])\s+', text.strip())

document = Document('bebe.docx')

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    sentence_buffer = ""
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        sentence_buffer += run.text
        style = get_text_style(run)

        sentences = split_into_sentences(sentence_buffer)
        if len(sentences) > 1:
            for sentence in sentences[:-1]:
                print(f"Propoziție: {sentence}, Stil: {style}")
            sentence_buffer = sentences[-1]

    if sentence_buffer:
        print(f"Propoziție: {sentence_buffer}, Stil: {style}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The original problem may have been related to how the Styles were applied in the Word document. Yes, you must **Create a New Style** for the entire document. And save it.

**Such a problem usually happens when you copy the content from a web page into a docx file.**

I think that Python does not see the italic font in the docx, because in the html class it is not specified in the css and the fact that it is Italic.

For example. In a html page, If there is `<em>` and `</em>` on a paragraph with `text_obisnuit_1` class, and  this html class  doesn't have in it `font-style: italic;`  declared in css, then Word .docx will see the Italic font, but Python will not recognize it. Even Word will not recognize it in the syles, even if it will be visible in docx.

**So, be sure the html classes have in it italic styles. Then, you can test again Python code in order to verify the results:**

```
from docx import Document
import re

def print_sentence_style(paragraph):
    sentence = ""
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        sentence += run.text
        style = f"Bold: {'True' if run.bold else 'False'}, Italic: {'True' if run.italic else 'False'}"
        print(f"Run text: '{run.text}', Style: {style}")

    # Împărțirea textului în propoziții pentru afișare ulterioară
    sentences = re.split(r'(?<=[.!?])\s+', sentence.strip())
    for sent in sentences:
        print(f"Sentence: '{sent}'")

document = Document('bebe.docx')
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    print("New paragraph:")
    print_sentence_style(paragraph)
```